# Change mobile layout in responsive theme

Tags: magento-1.9

In a responsive theme for v1.9, Which file should I edit to change the default layout to 1 column, in mobile browsers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is CSS question and should be asked in "stackoverflow.com".

Answer (score 0):

Responsive designs do not care what device you are using.
It cares about display width/height (size).

If you need to change the layout/display according to the device, then you are moving away from responsive, and into 'separate design/layout per device' , which can each still be responsive, but that kinda defeats the point of having a responsive design.

You should be able to manipulate the page display via media queries. If you cannot do that, with media queries, for the page, on smaller devices, then there may be a need to restructure the HTML for the page, making it possible to manipulate with media queries in your css.